# C# Access instance of generic type argument at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, generics, polly

I have a handle exception method for my Polly IAsyncPolicy defined as such:

```
Handle<ApiException>(ApiException ex)
{
 /// do stuff
}
```

An ApiException can be either generic or non-generic:

`public class ApiException`

and

`public class ApiException<TResult>`

I know that an instance of the generic type will have a Property called Result of type TResult, which will always inherit from a type called BaseResponse.

There are many many classes that inherit from BaseResponse. I want to avoid having to write exception handlers for them all and do it all in the one handler.

At runtime, I want to

a) determine that ex is either a generic or non-generic instance of ApiException and

b) get a reference to the instance if it is generic, and access the "Result" property

I can do a) easily enough with ex.GetType().IsGenericType

b) is proving troublesome

I have tried:

```
        if (ex is ApiException<> apiE)
        {

        }
```

But I need a type to go in the `<>`

I know that type will always inherit from a type called `BaseResponse` so I tried,

```
        if (ex is ApiException<BaseResponse> apiE)
        {

        }
```

but it's not specific enough and returns false for child inheritors e.g `ApiException<AuthResponse>` where `AuthResponse : BaseResponse`

Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: Why you don't have two methods, one for the generic and one for the non-generic version?

Comment: What do you intend to do with the result property? You don't have any compile-time type for it, so you are quite limited in what to do with it without just using more reflection, or 'dynamic'. Overall, generics play poorly with 'at runtime'.

Comment: @TimSchmelter because there are many types that TResult could be so I would need many methods. I only need to access properties on the base TBaseResult which all TResults will inherit from

Comment: @JonasH it is tricky for me to put compile-time constraints on the method as ApiException and ApiException<TResult> are generated by a tool (NSwag) without any compile time constraints. Perhaps there's a clue there, maybe I can fiddle with the NSwag settings to achieve compile time constraints.

I intend to access properties on TResult which are defined on it's parent TBaseResult

Comment: [expert, you may use covariance](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LZj0SE)

Comment: Or https://dotnetfiddle.net/vYsz9J if class is needed as Handle generic argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed get the type of the generic parameter, you can also read that `Result` using reflection. Whether you can do anything meaningful with it kind of depends.

```
static void Handle<T>(T ex) where T : ApiException
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    if(!type.IsGenericType)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{type} is non generic");
    }
    else
    {
        var gType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        Console.WriteLine($"{type} is generic, the type is {gType}");
        
        var result = type.GetProperty("Result");
        var obj = (BaseResponse)result.GetValue(ex);
        Console.WriteLine($"Got Result={obj.Name}");
    }
        
}
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DpyZpk

---

My "It depends" comment was before I noticed that you commented

> I only need to access properties on the base TBaseResult which all TResults will inherit from

So you're in luck.... you can cast that `Result`

```
var obj = (BaseResponse)result.GetValue(ex);
// You can call any methods/properties on the base  type
```

Comment: Solid, thanks! I thought it might get reflect-y, but I didn't know how to implement. Cheers